# how to set left and top margin to a frame layout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-framelayout, layoutmargins

I have a **`framelayout`** inside a relative layout and i want to move frame layout a bit to the left and top as a whole. I have been using **`setLeft()`** and **`setTop()`** method. It is stretching the view but still it is okay for my purpose. My problem is I want the original unstretched frame layout back when I want it. But setting **`setRight()`** and putting the same parameter doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Comment: is your framelayout to your parent view?

Comment: Relative Layout is the parent view of framelayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setMargin to your framelayout

```
val par = framelayout?.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams

par.rightMargin = 10
par.leftMargin = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set Margin to your view like set padding. You need a Layout params for your frame layout then set margin to layout param.

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```